# Binding an object

Tags: angularjs

I have this HTML code:

```
<td style="max-width:29px" ng-repeat="measure in item.measures"
    ng-click="changeValues(measure)" ng-model="formData.dataChanged">
  {{measure.column[measure.column.length-1].value}}
  <span ng-show="measure.column.length>1">*</span>
</td>
```

What can be done to do binding of a values with this format? I want this object `{{measure.column[measure.column.length-1].value}}` to be valid other array value.

I try it with something like this:

```
$scope.measure = ($scope.measure) ? $scope.measure : {};
$scope.measure.column = ($scope.measure.column) ? $scope.measure.column : {};
$scope.measure.column[$scope.measure.column.length-1].value = $scope.popupData[0].valueItem;
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your question. Its difficult to understand

Comment: @Sravan I want to match this object to a numeric value for example...  $scope.measure.column[$scope.measure.column.length-1].value = 105;

Comment: still not clear. can you please explain in details.

Comment: The `ng-model` directive does not work on `<td>` elements. `length` is not a property of objects.

Comment: from the syntax, I think you want an array at `measure.column`: `$scope.measure.column = ($scope.measure.column) ? $scope.measure.column : [];`

Comment: The `ng-repeat` creates a child scope which will hide `measure` property from parent scope.

Comment: I explain the operation of the code, when you click on the "td" it's opens a popup window, the user fills in an input. This value of the input is saved in a matrix that value is ($ scope.popupData [0] .valueItem)
I need the value of my "td", it changes for ($scope.popupData [0] .valueItem)